# Swift subclass of AVAudioSession not working at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a Swift subclass of AVAudioSession as:

```
//  AudioSession.swift

class AudioSession: AVAudioSession
```

and I have some methods in it, for ex:

```
func setToSpeaker() throws {
 ...
}
```

now, when I call this method from an objC class:

```
[[AudioSession sharedInstance] setToSpeakerAndReturnError: nil];
```

This compiles fine, and it seems that the compiler has all the necessary information about the swift class being a subclass of AVAudioSession as I'm also able to call superclass methods on it such as:

```
[[AudioSession shared] setActive: true error: nil];
```

but when I run this the program crashes on calling any method of this subclass, with error:

> '-[AVAudioSession setToSpeakerAndReturnError:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170008510'

I looked further in the debugger and found that at runtime any instance of my subclass 'AudioSession' is treated as an instance of 'AVAudioSession' that's why there's an unrecognized selector exception.

Why this might be happening, can anyone give a clue?

Answer (score 0):

As I can not see the code inside your setToSpeaker function how you start the AudioEngine or what ever which is marked as throws. e.g audioEngine.start() can throws and you already have marked your setToSpeaker function also throws try to mark your function with fileprivate

```
fileprivate func setToSpeaker() throws {
     .....

   // here if your using the do try and catch for your audioEngine.start()
  // now you can simply start the audio engine
  audioEngine.start()
}
```

As your function can throw you have to use try and catch in objective-C

```
@try {
   [[AudioSession sharedInstance] setToSpeaker];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Something missing...");
}
@finally {

}
```

Or don't mark your function with throws in your swift file

```
func setToSpeaker() {

  do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        // if audioEngine throws now just printing the localized string
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

call directly from Objective-C No need for @try and @catch

Comment: This is not the problem, what I stated is that the code inside the function never gets executed as program crashes before reaching the function. Reason of crash is unrecognized selector sent to instance. At runtime the function setToSpeaker is just not available.

Comment: do you import swift.h in your objective-c class?

Comment: yes, that's why it's accessible at compile time, otherwise the code wouldn't even compile

Comment: You can try to mark your function **@objc** . Otherwise without some more info or the project will be difficult to say something